# strange transition between integer and array

Tags: c, arrays, extern

I have defined a global variable `SEIS_FORMAT` as an integer. But when I use it in the external function, I define it as an array `SEIS_FORMAT[6]` and use it as `SEIS_FORMAT[0]`, as follows:

1.MAIN() code:

```
#include "head.h"

int SEIS_FORMAT=5; /*global variable*/

int main() 
{ 
   int a=2;
   float b=3.5;
   f1(&a, &b); 
   return 0; 
}
```

2.function code: "f1.c"

```
#include "head.h"

void f1(int *a, float *b)
{
  extern int SEIS_FORMAT[6];  //different from the main()
  printf("a=%d,b=%f,c=%d\n",*a,*b,SEIS_FORMAT[0]); //notice the use of SEIS_FORMAT
}
```

Why can I always get the correct answer: `a=2,b=3.500000,c=5`?
The definitions of `SEIS_FORMAT` are equivalent to each other?

Comment: weird but probably undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly undefined behavior, so anything is possible.

As to why it seems to work, the linker doesn't know anything about data types, it just knows that the name `SEIS_FORMAT` refers to a specific memory location. It's initialized by the main program as a single integer, but `f1()` then treats that memory location as the beginning of an array. Element `0` of the array corresponds to the integer that was initialized in the main program.